# Does the data("key", value) method set data- attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Will the jQuery `$("..").data("key", value)` method set the data-key **attribute** if one is present?

[Adam Freeman's Pro jQuery](http://www.apress.com/9781430240952) states that it does:

> **Tip** The data method takes the data attributes into account when
>   setting values as well. When you specify a key, such a [sic] product, the
>   data method checks to see whether there is a corresponding HTML5 data
>   attribute, such as data-product. If there is, then the value you
>   specified is assigned to the attribute. If not, then the data is
>   stored internally by jQuery.

But I thought that it didn't, and the test that I ran implies that it doesn't.  (I checked the errata section—nothing)

Full code is below, but the short of it is that when I set the data-name attribute by calling the `attr` method, the attribute value changes and can be seen in the chrome elements tab, and retrieved into `newValue`.  When I set it with the data method, neither of these conditions are satisfied; it seems as though using `data()` always sets the value internally and never on the attribute, even if one is present.

Unfortunately, the [docs' only mention of html5 data-attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) is in the section of the data method that takes only a key, and returns the concomitant value; the description of `data("key", value)` doesn't seem to mention html5 data-attributes at all.

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var oldValue = $("#d").data("name");
            alert("old value " + oldValue);

            $("#d").data("name", "Adam");
            //$("#d").attr("data-name", "Adam");

            var newValue = $("#d").attr("data-name");
            alert("new value " + newValue);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="d" data-name="none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jQuery's .data() method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#notes-1):

> Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform
>   support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does
>   not allow data to be attached via expando properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Adam Freeman's description is incorrect, or at least not completely accurate.

According to the jQuery documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object.

This implies that jQuery pulls these attributes into its own internal representation, rather than overriding the values in the actual attributes.

A quick perusal of the code suggests the same.

Comment: This is correct. Any attributes you add to an element that start with "data-" are put into the internal data object, but any changes to those values are not reflected in the visible attribute. Nor are any data values added to the data object added as visible attributes of the element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it uses the `data=` if it's there and doesn't throw an error.

[Take a look for yourself:](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L324)

```
function dataAttr( elem, key, data ) {
    // If nothing was found internally, try to fetch any
    // data from the HTML5 data-* attribute
    if ( data === undefined && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {

        var name = "data-" + key.replace( rmultiDash, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();

        data = elem.getAttribute( name );

        if ( typeof data === "string" ) {
            try {
                data = data === "true" ? true :
                data === "false" ? false :
                data === "null" ? null :
                jQuery.isNumeric( data ) ? +data :
                    rbrace.test( data ) ? jQuery.parseJSON( data ) :
                    data;
            } catch( e ) {}

            // Make sure we set the data so it isn't changed later
            jQuery.data( elem, key, data );

        } else {
            data = undefined;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.data()` function doesn't interact with the HTML5 `data-*` attributes at all, other than taking the initial values from them; I'm not entirely sure **when** this is done, though - another answer suggests it's done at the first call to `.data()`, which may be correct (it definitely makes sense).

Using `.attr()` to specify a new value for a `data-*` attribute doesn't modify the value that jQuery has stored to access using `.data()`. To illustrate, take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj6SU/). If you inspect the `<div>` element and then click on the button, you can see that whilst the attribute on the element has its value changed the two `console.log()` calls output the same value.